# Tests failing after updating from 13.0.0 to latest 14.0.0 version of ngx-masonry library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, karma-jasmine

After updating to latest stable version of library `ngx-masonry` 14.0.0 tests failed. They had release yesterday (24.10.2022.) and here is the link to their changelog: https://github.com/wynfred/ngx-masonry/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Basically they added Ivy build since they were using ViewEngine on older versions. I suppose that this error is connected to that migration to newer Angular compiler. On project we use Angular version 14.

After running `npm i ngx-masonry@14.0.0` update was successful without any vulnerabilities.

In order for me to test it, I run `ng test` for my Angular application to make sure everything is fine. The failing test is basically the basic one which tests if the component is getting created. The following error was thrown in couple of components that rely on `ngx-masonry` library: **`ReferenceError: require is not defined`**

[image]

[image]

Since this is quite fresh issue (<24hrs old) probably more developers will run into it when they upgrade version to 14.

Link to the issue opened right now on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/wynfred/ngx-masonry/issues/98

Maybe we are missing something or this could be solved easily. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of the library have just released `14.0.1` version which contains the fix. After you run `npm i ngx-masonry@14.0.1` everything should be fine. Tests are passing as expected and app compiles successfully.